# adb shell says no device found, but adb -s <serialno> shell works

Tags: android, windows, adb

I'm having a curious situation with the `adb shell` command.

```
adb devices
```

shows my device connected as expected; however when I try

```
adb shell
```

with no arguments, it responds `error: no device found`. HOWEVER, when I run

```
adb -s <device_serial_number_from_adb_devices> shell
```

I'm able to get into the shell successfully. Which is fine, except that I'm having some other adb-related problems due to it not connecting with default params.

Additional info:

- usb debugging enabled (again, works when I specify the serialno)
- W7/64bit laptop
- adb shell works fine on another macosx machine, so the problem seems to be specific to my android installation
- I've uninstalled and reinstalled the google usb driver from the android SDK
- restarted adb server (kill-server, start-server)
- tried `android adb update`

Can any adb experts shed some light? Thanks!

Comment: do you have multiple devices plugged in to the computer?

Comment: no, just one. afaik, the error in that case would be 'error: more than one device or emulator.' No emulators running either btw.

Comment: Have you tried kill-server, start-server ?

Comment: yep, adb kill-server / adb start-server

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer to this but I had the exact same problem recently. This is a result of setting the ANDROID_SERIAL variable in system variables. I had done so when trying to set up CI builds (Cukes and Units) to run on a physical device and emulator separately (ADB wasn't playing nice when both builds were being run on the same phy

Comment: thanks for the info DigitalMoss. I'm not working on this at the moment but I'll definitely make a note for the future.